# Reference request: statement about jointly Gaussian RV

Tags: normal-distribution, references, random-variable, gaussian-mixture-distribution

I found a theorem online https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ananth/223Spr07/jointlygaussian.pdf

[image]

Is there a secondary reference for this theorem?